# How can you pass user input from a text box into a function securely, and then output to DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a javascript/jquery beginner and am building my first little script to learn (just client-side javascript).  I already wrote it and was excited that it started to work, but now I'm stumbling on articles about "XSS" vulnerabilities, and things about NEVER using jquery .html(), .append(), or any javascript writing to DOM that involves "user input."  That it's a bad practice and you can be hacked, etc.  However, none of the articles / explanations are clear to me in terms of what this really means.

It seems like taking "user input" and passing it into functions, and then showing output based on the user input is an obvious use of javascript, especially for web apps and the browser. Or am I completely missing something ?

Below is a basic idea of what I've done.  I'm not directly appending the user input to the DOM, but using the user input in a function that later appends to the DOM:

1) user enters text into text box (hopefully a number - a dollar amount) and clicks a "submit" button

2) Then I set a variable equal to whatever the user input into the text box and make it a jquery object

3) then I use the variable in an "if" statement condition (a <= condition)

4) then, if the condition is true, cycle through an array and output a string that contains HTML and text using .append()

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#output").empty();
        var spendAmount = $("input[name=dollarAmount]").val();
        var totalAmount = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<GameArrayLength; i++) {
                if (totalAmount + GameArray[i].price <= spendAmount) {
                    $("#output").append("<p>"+ "<span>"+GameArray[i].name + "</span> ---------   $" + GameArray[i].price + "</p>");
                    totalAmount += GameArray[i].price;
                    };
                };
            });
```

I really appreciate any explanation, because I can't figure out what any of these security articles mean and want to make sure I am learning properly.

EDIT *** :  here is a link to one of the articles   http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/DOM-based_XSS   It mentions vulnerabilities even if you just using JS (no server side of databases)

and this article:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: as a simple test try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m5MgC/2/

Comment: so you can in the fiddle instead of printing the text `<script>alert("123")</script>` to the `div`, it actually executes the script....

Comment: so to escape from this you can use .text() instead of html like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m5MgC/3/

Comment: and you can append a text node instead of appending the string like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m5MgC/4/

Comment: The thing to take away from the articles is that you want to clean and escape user input that you intend on using.  Basically, if it's all client-side, you want to make sure that whatever input is taken and printed out has been converted into a value that can't alter the site's HTML as @ArunPJohny illustrated. You'll need to convert HTML to HTML character entities to prevent this. If you're passing values to the server and eventually a database, make sure it's escaped.

Comment: thanks for the response.  If you are not doing any server-side ... just javascript... do you have to bother with any of that ?  Everything is being evaluated just within the javascript script itself.

Comment: I found the brief article/resource:  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/DOM-based_XSS    Do you guys understand what it's talking about ... it seemed like it was talking about vulnerabilities even without any database/server interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bit of a security misconception. The code you posted is perfectly secure as it is. Assuming the field input[name=dollarAmount] is not somehow filled out by the url or a database.

Cross-site scripting in the form I think you're referring to involves a malicious user basically creating a link that they have included Javascript in the url/page somehow. So that malicious code can then steal cookies, user inputs, etc. But it has to be transferable. If the user can't somehow make a link that can permanently store/locate or represent the malicious code, it's perfectly harmless. Technically speaking, I can execute Javascript on any website, but it only affects me. If I wanted to affect somebody else, I would have to somehow send them a link or message that somehow includes the malicious code.

With Javascript, the number one security flaw I've seen is hashes. They're the number sign that goes after the url. For example, www.example.com/picnics **#heading_2**

Let's say someone had a Javascript function like this on the page. Taken from http://ma.la/jquery_xss.

> ```
> <script>
>     $(function(){
>         try { $(location.hash) } catch(e) {}
>     })
> </script>
> ```

This is insecure Javascript. As you can see, it takes the url hash (`location.hash`) and, thanks to Jquery, basically evaluates it. So now someone could add malicious code beyond the hash. A script function that steals sessions maybe. They could then send me the link, I click on the link, and without knowing, the script they wrote is executed in my web browser.

In your example, there is no way for malicious code to be sent to anyone. Of course, someone could send me an email with the link to your site and then give me instructions to copy and paste their code into the input on the form. But this should trigger warning bells, and most likely if the user could fall for that, they might as well just ask for the password.

Security concerns come up when you start storing user input (in a url, database, etc.). If you intend to store user input in a database, **you should never** trust Javascript to properly remove malicious code. It is beyond trivial to sidestep. If you want to store information in a url, I recommend using a whitelist approach and staying away from certain Jquery functions. For example, I would have a switch statement comparing strings that I would expect (for example location.hash == 'heading1') , and if it matches, run a function (maybe scroll to a section of a page). If it doesn't match, do nothing. That way only text that I expect would ever be used.

So in short, if the information is never stored (in a database, etc.) and is impossible to recreate simply by clicking a link or something similar, you don't have to worry about Javascript being the root of the cross-site scripting problems. Any malicious code they write is on their machine and their machine only.

Comment: appreciate the response.  This seems logical (only having to worry if using databses / serverside), but I thought I read even just altering the DOM with JS can have issues.   Below is a link to one of the articles - I dont understand it but it seems like they don't mention anything server side.  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/DOM-based_XSS

Comment: @codester 
Yes, they are also talking about using the the URL `document.location` for creating DOM on the page. This is dangerous as it provids a method for sending malicious code in links.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I'll just stick to JS/Jquery and no server stuff while I learn (which I planned on doing anyway(.  Thanks again Travis